# Mysql Real Escape String PHP Function Adding "\" to My Field Entry

Tags: php, mysql, magic-quotes

I am submitting a form to my MySQL database using PHP.

I am sending the form data through the `mysql_real_escape_string($content)` function.

When the entry shows up in my database (checking in phpMyAdmin) all of my double quotes and single quotes are escaped.

I'm fairly certain this is a PHP configuration issue?

so:

```
$content = 'Hi, my name is Jascha and my "favorite" thing to do is sleep';
mysql_real_escape_string($content);
$query = 'INSERT INTO DB...'
```

comes up in my database as:

Hi, my name is Jascha and my \"favorite" thing to do is sleep

Who do I tell what to do?  (I cannot access the php.ini).

Comment: Can you post the rest of your query?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173212/mysqlrealescapestring-leaving-slashes-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you akiller, I did a search for this question before posting it, i guess I was using the wrong phrasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take magic quotes into account when retrieving request data. If [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) is `true`, then you need to run [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the input. Best way would be to write a function for that. Something like:

```
function get_string($array, $index, $default = null) {
    if (isset($array[$index]) && strlen($value = trim($array[$index])) > 0) {
        return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($value) : $value;
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

..which you can use as

```
$input = get_string($_POST, 'input');
```

..instead of

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
```

Do the same for trivial stuff like `get_number()`, `get_boolean()`, `get_array()` and so on.

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting your $content data from a form *(and not "as-is" in the PHP code)*, maybe you're having a problem because of Magic quotes *(see [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc))*

Basically :

> When magic_quotes are on, all `'`
>   (single-quote), `"` (double quote), `\`
>   (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with
>   a backslash automatically

If magic quotes are enabled *(you can check this in the ouput of [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo), for instance)*, you'll be getting that kind of "double escaping" :

- Those characters will be escaped once by magic quotes,
- And, then, they'll be escaped a second time by `mysql_real_escape_string`

The good solution, in this case, is not to stop using `mysql_real_escape_string`, but to disabled magic_quotes_gpc in your configuration...

... But, as you don't have access to it, you'll actually have to "revert" the effect of magic quotes, calling [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) on the input you're getting as `$_GET` and `$_POST`, before begining using it.

Note : it's an advice that's given on the manual page of [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) *(quoting)* :

> Note: If [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) is
>   enabled, first apply
>   [`stripslashes()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to the data.
>   Using this function on data which has
>   already been escaped will escape the
>   data twice.

Comment: huhu ^^ not, there is not ^^ But glad you got a solution to your problem :-)

Comment: So does that mean I'm stuck with inserting the data into my database with the slashes but I have to stripslashes() before displaying it on my page *OR* can I do a mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['value'])) before I run the insert?

Ahhh... just tested it.

mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_REQUEST['value']))  works.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is a little late, but as a noob to php I needed something really simple. 
So I am using this code below to fix the problem described by the OP with magic_quotes_gpc
I have a server running php 5.2.8 and one running 5.3

My web app is using datatables.net to display information. 
I started getting JSON errors when data was saved with special characters escaped in the database.

My Development machine uses 5.3 where this wasn't neccesary, but with php 5.2.8 I needed to use the stripslashes function in order to save the values to my database.

```
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
// hack for php 5.2.8 //
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
     $description = stripslashes($description); 
     //echo "description: $description";
    }
```

I realize this is basically the same answer as above, but for me it seemed more my style. 
Hopefully this will help others in the same boat as I am.....

Comment: stripslashes should never be used in the same place with mysql_real_escape_string. latter one is database related while first one is input related.